# Jquery UI, if check-mark checked drop draggable div into droppable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable div and a droppable div, when check-mark is checked i want to move the draggable into droppable.

Also no access to html.

Tried using append but this does not works as it needs for me in this place.

```
//draggable id #r1, droppable id #td1
if($("#Q1v2_1").is(":checked")){
    drop: function(event, ui) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems very abstract. I would advise the following without a more complete answer.

```
//dragable id #r1, dropable id #td1
if($("#Q1v2_1").is(":checked")){
    $("#td1").on("drop", function(e, ui) {
    });
}
```

Otherwise, if you're doing this inside your droppable init:

```
$("#td1").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui){
    if(!$("#Q1v2_1").is(":checked")){
      // Is Not Checked
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

This would check the status of the checkbox first, and if it's unchecked, prevent drop.